# How can I see commit history timestamps in Xcode 9?

Tags: version-control, timestamp, commit, xcode9

Currently I can only see the date that the commit was made on, but in Xcode 8 it included the actual time of commit. When you make multiple commits a day it is useful to see the time stamp.

Is there a way to turn on timestamps for the new Source Control tab in Xcode 9?

Answer (score 0):

If you navigate to `View > Version Editor > Show Log View` and select your project folder (the root directory) on the left-most file navigation panel, you will see your commit history for the entire project with date and time in the Editor Panel. You can also select individual files to see their respective commit history.

Unrelated to XCode, you can always go to the terminal, navigate to your project directory and enter `git log`.